# Paste function to add backslash in r

Tags: r, paste, names

This may be a very specialized request, but I want to paste a backslash (\) at the end of a file.path string before every file in R. For some reason, R does not like the function: sep="\" and I do not know why... Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
# Image files 
files <- c("image1.bmp", "image2.bmp", "image3.bmp", "image4.bmp", "image5.bmp")

# Pasting file paths and file names 
file.paths <- paste("C:/Users/John/Desktop/images/", files, sep="\")

# Desired output 
C:/Users/John/Desktop/images\image1.bmp
C:/Users/John/Desktop/images\image2.bmp
C:/Users/John/Desktop/images\image3.bmp
C:/Users/John/Desktop/images\image4.bmp
C:/Users/John/Desktop/images\image5.bmp
```

Comment: Try with \\. Will probably appear as double backslash but in reality it's one if you `cat` it

Comment: Also, you will want to use `paste()`, not `paste0()` when specifying `sep`

Comment: `paste0` has no `sep` argument. You probably meant `paste("C:/Users/John/Desktop/images/", files, sep="\\")` ?

Comment: Yes, paste is the correct function

Comment: As already mentioned by @arg0naut91 , doesn't `paste("C:/Users/John/Desktop/images", files, sep="\\")` work for you?

Comment: `file.path()` may be a helpful function to do that OS-independently (unless you always want to use a backslash where `paste0` is still your best friend ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\` works, but it appears as double backslash in console output, however it is right you cant use `message` or `cat` to see how it looks naturally.

```r
file.paths <- paste0("C:/Users/John/Desktop/images\\" , files)

message(file.paths[1])
cat(file.paths[1])

fileConn<-file("outputtest.txt")
writeLines(file.paths, fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

saving in text file output :

[image]